# mysql insert multiple rows is data being partially saved

Tags: mysql

Suppose I  have a query like this

```
INSERT INTO mytable(`title`, `name`) VALUES  // row1
(`title1`, `name1`), // row 2
(`title2`, `name2`), // row 3
(`title3`, `name3 is too long for the table corresponding field`); // row 4
```

and trying to save into db I get error that like `data truncated for column name`, so I wanted to ask whether the rows (row 2 and row 3) and/or third row's `title` field will be saved in the table , or in case of this error no data will be saved(in case if, smth like it first 'checks' whether all the data can be saved properly and then tries to save)
Thanks

Comment: why don't you try it out?

Comment: It will not save anything

Comment: @AshReva It saved to db for me.

Comment: FWIW, you can't insert using backticks. Change them to `'title1'`

Comment: @hjpotter92 i tried it in sql fiddle and it didnt saved any rows http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mysql 5.6.13 the following SQL fails to insert any record:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(title, name) VALUES 
('title1', 'name1'), 
('title2', 'name2'), 
('title3', 'name3 is too long for the table corresponding field');
```

if you want the data to be truncated and have all three records inserted use "IGNORE":

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable(title, name) VALUES 
('title1', 'name1'), 
('title2', 'name2'), 
('title3', 'name3 is too long for the table corresponding field');
```